# slony1-2.2.1 installation error

Tags: postgresql, makefile, ubuntu-12.04, slony

I am trying to install slony1-2.2.1 in ubuntu 12.04 + postgresql-9.3. The configuration is done but when i am firing "make all" command the following error is shown:

root@administrator:/home/priyatam/Desktop/icons/slony1-2.2.1# make all

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/priyatam/Desktop/icons/slony1-2.2.1/src'
make[2]: Entering directory`/home/priyatam/Desktop/icons/slony1-2.2.1/src/parsestatements'
./test-scanner < /dev/null > emptytestresult.log
./test-scanner < ./test_sql.sql > test_sql.log`` `
./test-scanner < ./cstylecomments.sql > cstylecomments.log
make[2]: Leaving directory ``/home/priyatam/Desktop/icons/slony1-2.2.1/src/parsestatements'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/priyatam/Desktop/icons/slony1-2.2.1/src/slon'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for`all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/priyatam/Desktop/icons/slony1-2.2.1/src/slon'
make[2]: Entering directory`/home/priyatam/Desktop/icons/slony1-2.2.1/src/slonik'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/priyatam/Desktop/icons/slony1-2.2.1/src/slonik'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/priyatam/Desktop/icons/slony1-2.2.1/src/backend'
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -I../.. -fpic -I/usr/include/postgresql -c -o slony1_funcs.o slony1_funcs.c
slony1_funcs.c:23:23: fatal error: miscadmin.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [slony1_funcs.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/priyatam/Desktop/icons/slony1-2.2.1/src/backend'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/priyatam/Desktop/icons/slony1-2.2.1/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2

please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of observations before the answer.

1. Why are you running "make all" as root? It might be required for "make install", but try to avoid running as root otherwise.
2. Why are you building the source in "Desktop/icons/..."? Don't you think maybe in six months you might want to find it again? Consider putting your source in /usr/local/src or somewhere similar.

OK - the error is pretty clear. File "slony1_funcs.c" on line 23 tries to include "miscadmin.h" and fails. If you had googled "slony postgresql miscadmin.h no such file or directory" then you'd have seen several cases where people had the same problem (and solved it). Consider searching next time.

The problem is that it can't find the source headers for PostgreSQL. Since you're on ubuntu the package will be called something like 'postgresql-server-dev-9.3'.

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard. I just needed to install postgresql-server-dev-9.3 package.

Comment: Actually i did the installation successfully but while creating a new slony cluster in pgadmin,i am getting following error:                                                      ERROR:  function _sample.storenode(integer, unknown, boolean) does not exist
LINE 6413: SELECT _sample.storeNode(99, 'dfdf', false);
                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.                                  I have set the binary path properly but still not working.